# What's the time unit of this timedelta?

Tags: python, time, timedelta

```
import time
from datetime import timedelta

start = time.time()
...
end = time.time()

print('Total time spent: {}'.format(str(timedelta(seconds=end - start))))
```

For example, one output could be:

```
0:00:00.395616
```

The fist 3 must be hours, minutes and seconds. What about the '.395616' part? Is it millseconds or microseconds, or even seconds?

Comment: Is that not obvious?  Hours, then minutes, then the seconds are a floating point value.  That's about 4/10 second.

Comment: The `.` in this case is just a decimal point; maybe you're from a locale that uses the `,` character as a decimal point and thought it was a separator? The only separators here are the `:` characters.

Comment: So it's a decimal of seconds, not mill-seconds?

Comment: @marlon With the `.`, it's a decimal of seconds. If you ignore the the dot (decimal point), you can take 3 digits and say it's "395 milliseconds" but you can't say it's "395,616 milliseconds" coz that's not how decimal places work and it would also become 395 _seconds_, which is wrong. You could say "395616 **micro**seconds". So yes,  '.395616' is in seconds. Like "0.5 apples" doesn't mean one or two apple slices, it's just half an apple.

Comment: 0.395616 seconds, 3.95616 deciseconds, 39.5616 centiseconds, 395.616 milliseconds, 395,616 microseconds: whatever units you want to use, they all describe the same interval of time.

Comment: The units are 10**-6 seconds aka [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second#SI_multiples).